# NullPointerException while referencing checkboxes in another class?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jcheckbox

Why's there a null pointer exception for referencing the checkboxes in other classes?  Is it because I have to make the `CheckBox` graphically visible in order to make them not `null`?

Here's the error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at
>   com.company.Output.Constraint.removePersonWithConstraint1(Constraint.java:125)

and line 125 is located in the line `System.out.println(inputChange.wk1.isSelected());` in `removePersonWithConstraint1()`

```
package com.company.Output;

import com.company.Input.Input;
import com.company.Input.InputChange;
import com.company.Input.InputMain;

import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by paull on 6/6/2016.
 */
public class Constraint {

    Input input;
    DateRange dateRange;
    Output output;
    InputMain inputMain;
    InputChange inputChange;

    Calendar calendar;

    ArrayList<String> listOfFirstSundays;
    ArrayList<String> listOfSecondSundays;
    ArrayList<String> listOfThirdSundays;
    ArrayList<String> listOfFourthSundays;
    ArrayList<String> listOfFifthSundays;

    public Constraint(Input input, DateRange dateRange,Output output,InputMain inputMain,InputChange inputChange) {
        this.input = input;
        this.dateRange = dateRange;
        this.output = output;
        this.inputMain = inputMain;
        this.inputChange = inputChange;

        listOfFirstSundays = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfSecondSundays = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfThirdSundays = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfFourthSundays = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfFifthSundays = new ArrayList<String>();

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }


    public void constraint1(int year, int month) {
        calendar.set(year,month - 1,1);
        int monthDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int monthlySundayCounter = 0;

        String ithSunday = "";

        for (int i = 1; i <= monthDays; i++) {
            calendar.set(year,month - 1,i);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            String dayString = year + "/" + month + "/" + i; //setup the daystring
            //System.out.println(dayString);
            if (day == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                monthlySundayCounter++;//count which sunday it is in a month

                //System.out.println(year + "/" + month + "/" + i + " is the " + monthlySundayCounter + " th Sunday."); //this line works

                for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                    //test
                    //System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0));
                    //System.out.println("dayString = " + dayString);
                    //System.out.println("output at " + j + "row and 0 column = " + output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0));
                    //System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).equals(dayString));

                    if (output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).equals(dayString)) {
                        //System.out.println("this works");
                        switch (monthlySundayCounter) {
                            case 1:
                                listOfFirstSundays.add(dayString);
                                //System.out.println(dayString + " is the 1st Sunday.");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                listOfSecondSundays.add(dayString);
                                //System.out.println(dayString + " is the 2nd Sunday.");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                listOfThirdSundays.add(dayString);
                                //System.out.println(dayString + " is the 3rd Sunday.");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                listOfFourthSundays.add(dayString);
                                //System.out.println(dayString + " is the 4th Sunday.");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                listOfFifthSundays.add(dayString);
                                //System.out.println(dayString + " is the 5th Sunday.");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removePersonWithConstraint1() {
        //for each person within the inputmain table
        //1. setCheckboxBasedOnConstraintText()
        //if (checkbox is checked for nth Sunday), then {delete him from every list (list of sat, list of eight, etc.) for that Sunday}
        for (int i = 0; i < inputMain.model.getRowCount(); i++) { //for each row within the inputmain table
            //reset all the checkboxes

            System.out.println(inputChange.wk1.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk2.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk3.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk4.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk5.isSelected());



            inputChange.wk1.setSelected(false);
            inputChange.wk2.setSelected(false);
            inputChange.wk3.setSelected(false);
            inputChange.wk4.setSelected(false);
            inputChange.wk5.setSelected(false);


            inputMain.setCheckboxBasedOnConstraintText(i); //set the checkbox based on the constraint text

            System.out.println(inputChange.wk1.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk2.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk3.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk4.isSelected());
            System.out.println(inputChange.wk5.isSelected());

            String name = inputMain.table.getValueAt(i,0).toString();//get the name of that person from inputmain
            System.out.println(name);

            if (inputChange.wk1.isSelected()) { //if the checkbox is checked
                System.out.println(inputChange.wk1.isSelected());
                for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                    for (String lofs : listOfFirstSundays) { //for every sunday within listoffirstsunday, if it equals to a sunday in the output tableresult
                        if (lofs.equals(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j, 0).toString())) {
                            System.out.println(lofs);
                            System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString());
                            //remove the person who chose that constraint
                            output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString().replaceAll((name),""); //(name) is a regular expression
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                if (inputChange.wk2.isSelected()) { //if the checkbox is checked
                    for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                        for (String lofs : listOfSecondSundays) { //for every sunday within listoffirstsunday, if it equals to a sunday in the output tableresult
                            if (lofs.equals(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j, 0).toString())) {
                                System.out.println(lofs);
                                System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString());
                                //remove the person who chose that constraint
                                output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString().replaceAll((name),""); //(name) is a regular expression
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (inputChange.wk3.isSelected()) { //if the checkbox is checked
                    for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                        for (String lofs : listOfThirdSundays) { //for every sunday within listoffirstsunday, if it equals to a sunday in the output tableresult
                            if (lofs.equals(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j, 0).toString())) {
                                System.out.println(lofs);
                                System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString());
                                //remove the person who chose that constraint
                                output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString().replaceAll((name),""); //(name) is a regular expression
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (inputChange.wk4.isSelected())  { //if the checkbox is checked
                    for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                        for (String lofs : listOfFourthSundays) { //for every sunday within listoffirstsunday, if it equals to a sunday in the output tableresult
                            if (lofs.equals(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j, 0).toString())) {
                                System.out.println(lofs);
                                System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString());
                                //remove the person who chose that constraint
                                output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString().replaceAll((name),""); //(name) is a regular expression
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (inputChange.wk5.isSelected()) { //if the checkbox is checked
                    for (int j = 0; j < output.dtm.getRowCount(); j++) {
                        for (String lofs : listOfFifthSundays) { //for every sunday within listoffirstsunday, if it equals to a sunday in the output tableresult
                            if (lofs.equals(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j, 0).toString())) {
                                System.out.println(lofs);
                                System.out.println(output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString());
                                //remove the person who chose that constraint
                                output.tableResult.getValueAt(j,0).toString().replaceAll((name),""); //(name) is a regular expression
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }


}
```

InputChange as requested.  The checkboxes are initialized I think.

```
    package com.company.Input;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by paull on 6/6/2016.
 */
public class InputChange {
    JLabel nameLabel;
    JLabel optionLabel;
    JLabel constraintLabel;
    JButton enter;
    JPanel labelPanel;
    JPanel jp2;
    JPanel jp3;
    JPanel jp4;
    JTextField nameText;
    String[] optionStrings;
    JComboBox<String> optionText;
    public JCheckBox wk1;
    public JCheckBox wk2;
    public JCheckBox wk3;
    public JCheckBox wk4;
    public JCheckBox wk5;

    String constraintText;

    JPanel checkboxPanel;

    private InputMain im;


    public InputChange(InputMain inputMain) {
        this.im = inputMain;
        nameLabel = new JLabel("");
        optionLabel = new JLabel("");
        constraintLabel = new JLabel("");
        enter = new JButton("");
        nameText = new JTextField(10);
        Options c = new Options();
        optionStrings = new String[]{c.satNight,c.sunEight,c.sunNineThirty,c.sunEleven,c.sunNight};
        optionText = new JComboBox<String>(optionStrings);
        wk1 = new JCheckBox("");
        wk2 = new JCheckBox("");
        wk3 = new JCheckBox("");
        wk4 = new JCheckBox("");
        wk5 = new JCheckBox("");
        constraintText = new String();
        checkboxPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10,30,10));


        int fontSize = 50;
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        optionLabel.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        constraintLabel.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        enter.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        nameText.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        optionText.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        wk1.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        wk2.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        wk3.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        wk4.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        wk5.setFont(new Font(nameLabel.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        //Image ticked = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Ticked.png");
        //Image unticked = ImageIO.s("Unticked.png");
        ImageIcon unticked = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Unticked.png"));
        Image utimg = unticked.getImage();
        //Icon tickedIcon = new ImageIcon(ticked.getScaledInstance(100,100, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        Icon untickedIcon = new ImageIcon(utimg.getScaledInstance(50,50, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        ImageIcon ticked = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Ticked.png"));
        Image timg = ticked.getImage();
        Icon tickedIcon = new ImageIcon(timg.getScaledInstance(50,50,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        wk1.setIcon(untickedIcon);
        wk2.setIcon(untickedIcon);
        wk3.setIcon(untickedIcon);
        wk4.setIcon(untickedIcon);
        wk5.setIcon(untickedIcon);
        wk1.setSelectedIcon(tickedIcon);
        wk2.setSelectedIcon(tickedIcon);
        wk3.setSelectedIcon(tickedIcon);
        wk4.setSelectedIcon(tickedIcon);
        wk5.setSelectedIcon(tickedIcon);

        checkboxPanel.add(wk1);
        checkboxPanel.add(wk2);
        checkboxPanel.add(wk3);
        checkboxPanel.add(wk4);
        checkboxPanel.add(wk5);

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10,30,10));
        namePanel.add(nameLabel);
        namePanel.add(nameText);

        JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10,30,10));
        optionPanel.add(optionLabel);
        optionPanel.add(optionText);

        JPanel constraintPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10,30,0));
        constraintPanel.add(constraintLabel);
        constraintPanel.add(checkboxPanel);


        labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;//Start everythin from the top
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;//place everything in the center

        gbc.weightx = 0.25;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        labelPanel.add(nameLabel,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        labelPanel.add(nameText,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        labelPanel.add(optionLabel,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        labelPanel.add(optionText,gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 10;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        labelPanel.add(constraintLabel,gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 1.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        labelPanel.add(checkboxPanel,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        labelPanel.add(enter,gbc);


//        InputMain i = new InputMain();
        //inputMain.table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null,inputMain.columns));//i.data,i.columns --> defaulttablemodel is defined in inputMain.java
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) inputMain.table.getModel();

        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setConstraintText();
                String[] data = new String[]{nameText.getText(),optionText.getSelectedItem().toString(),constraintText};
                model.addRow(data);

                nameText.setText("");
                wk1.setSelected(false);//To clear out the previous checkboxes
                wk2.setSelected(false);
                wk3.setSelected(false);
                wk4.setSelected(false);
                wk5.setSelected(false);

            }
        });
}
```

Here's where I created my constraint instance, and called the constranint:

```
package com.company.Output;

//import com.company.Input.InputMain;

import com.company.Input.Input;
import com.company.Input.InputChange;
import com.company.Input.InputMain;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * Created by paull on 29/5/2016.
 */
public class DateRange {

    JLabel topic;
    JLabel year1;
    JLabel month1;
    JLabel day1;
    JLabel till;
    JLabel year2;
    JLabel month2;
    JLabel day2;
    JTextField beginYear;
    JTextField beginMonth;
    JTextField beginDay;
    JTextField endYear;
    JTextField endMonth;
    JTextField endDay;
    JButton confirm;
    JPanel words;
    public JPanel pane;

    Calendar calendar;

    int beginYearInt;
    int beginMonthInt;
    int beginDayInt;

    int endYearInt;
    int endMonthInt;
    int endDayInt;

    Output op;
    private InputMain im;
    Input input;
    InputChange inputChange;

    Constraint constraint;

    public DateRange(InputMain im, Input input, InputChange inputChange) {
        topic = new JLabel("");
        year1 = new JLabel("");
        month1 = new JLabel("");
        day1 = new JLabel("");
        till = new JLabel("");
        year2 = new JLabel("");
        month2 = new JLabel("");
        day2 = new JLabel("");


        beginYear = new JTextField(3);
        beginMonth = new JTextField(2);
        beginDay = new JTextField(2);

        endYear = new JTextField(3);
        endMonth = new JTextField(2);
        endDay = new JTextField(2);

        confirm = new JButton("");

        words = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(3,10,3));
        pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        gbc.weighty = 1;//vertical axis ratio
        gbc.gridx = 0;//which goes first starts from left;integer
        gbc.gridy = 0;//which goes first starts from top;integer
        pane.add(topic,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 1;//vertical axis ratio
        gbc.gridx = 0;//which goes first starts from left;integer
        gbc.gridy = 1;//which goes first starts from top;integer
        words.add(beginYear);
        words.add(year1);
        words.add(beginMonth);
        words.add(month1);
        words.add(beginDay);
        words.add(day1);
        words.add(till);
        words.add(endYear);
        words.add(year2);
        words.add(endMonth);
        words.add(month2);
        words.add(endDay);
        words.add(day2);
        pane.add(words,gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 1;//vertical axis ratio
        gbc.gridx = 0;//which goes first starts from left;integer
        gbc.gridy = 2;//which goes first starts from top;integer
        pane.add(confirm,gbc);

        int fontSize = 50;
        topic.setFont(new Font(topic.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        words.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        beginYear.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        year1.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        year2.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        beginMonth.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        month1.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        month2.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        beginDay.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        day1.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        day2.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        till.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        endYear.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        endMonth.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        endDay.setFont(new Font(words.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));
        confirm.setFont(new Font(confirm.getName(),Font.PLAIN,fontSize));


        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //addColumnConfirmListener(2010,6,1);
        //datesOfSundaysInTheSameMonth();
        confirmActionListener();
        //datesOfSundaysInTheBeginningMonth();
        //datesOfSundaysInTheEndingMonth();

        this.im = im;
        //im = new InputMain();
        op = new Output(im);

        this.input = input;
        constraint = new Constraint(input,this,op,im,inputChange);
    }



    public void datesUsingIndicator() {
        //parse those integers immediately after clicking the confirm button
        beginYearInt = parseIntWithException(beginYear,-1);//Integer.parseInt(beginYear.getText()) ;
        beginMonthInt = parseIntWithException(beginMonth,-1);//Integer.parseInt(beginMonth.getText());
        beginDayInt = parseIntWithException(beginDay,-1);//Integer.parseInt(beginDay.getText());

        endYearInt = parseIntWithException(endYear,-1);//Integer.parseInt(endYear.getText());
        endMonthInt = parseIntWithException(endMonth,-1);//Integer.parseInt(endMonth.getText());
        endDayInt = parseIntWithException(endDay,-1);//Integer.parseInt(endDay.getText());

        int noOfMonths = 0;
        if (beginYearInt == endYearInt) { // for the case of same year
            //THIS PART WORKS PERFECT
            for (int i = beginMonthInt; i <= endMonthInt; i++) {
                noOfMonths++;
            }
            if (noOfMonths >= 3) {
                datesOfSundaysInTheBeginningMonth();
                for (int i = beginMonthInt + 1; i < endMonthInt; i++) {
                    datesOfSundaysInTheMiddleMonths(endYearInt,i);
                }
                datesOfSundaysInTheEndingMonth();
            }
            if (noOfMonths == 2) {
                datesOfSundaysInTheBeginningMonth();
                datesOfSundaysInTheEndingMonth();
            }
            if (noOfMonths == 1) {
                datesOfSundaysInTheSameMonth();
            }
        }
        if (beginYearInt != endYearInt){ //for the case of different year
            int noOfYears = 0;
            for (int i = beginYearInt; i <= endYearInt; i++) {
                noOfYears++;
            }
            //calcualtion of sundays start from here:
            datesOfSundaysInTheBeginningMonth(); //Till the end of first month
            int beginyrmonthcounter = beginMonthInt + 1; // starts from the second month
            while (beginyrmonthcounter <= 12) {
                datesOfSundaysInTheMiddleMonths(beginYearInt,beginyrmonthcounter); //2nd month till December
                beginyrmonthcounter++;
            } //first year ended

            if (noOfYears >= 3) {//this case only happens if number of years is larger than or equal to 3
                for (int i = beginYearInt + 1; i <= endYearInt - 1; i++) { //second year till the second last year
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) { //from jan till december
                        datesOfSundaysInTheMiddleMonths(i, j);
                    }
                }
            }

            int endyrmonthcounter = 1;
            while (endyrmonthcounter < endMonthInt) { //from january of last year till the month before endmonth
                datesOfSundaysInTheMiddleMonths(endYearInt,endyrmonthcounter);
                endyrmonthcounter++;
            }
            datesOfSundaysInTheEndingMonth();
        }
    }


    public void confirmActionListener() { //just enter the actual month.  The functions already -1ed the month for calendar

        confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //create an output frame

                OutputFrame of = new OutputFrame();
                of.add(op.outPanel);

                op.topic3.setText(beginYear.getText() + "/" + beginMonth.getText() + "/" + beginDay.getText() + " - "
                + endYear.getText() + "/" + endMonth.getText() + "/" + endDay.getText());

                //remove all the previous data in case the user clicks the confirm button once more time
                for (int i = op.tableResult.getRowCount()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    op.dtm.removeRow(i);
                }
                for (int i = im.listOfSat.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    im.listOfSat.remove(i);
                }
                for (int i = im.listOfEight.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    im.listOfEight.remove(i);
                }
                for (int i = im.listOfNineThirty.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    im.listOfNineThirty.remove(i);
                }
                for (int i = im.listOfEleven.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    im.listOfEleven.remove(i);
                }
                for (int i = im.listOfSunSix.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    im.listOfSunSix.remove(i);
                }

                datesUsingIndicator();

                im.addPersonToCorrectQueue();

                //TODO: removePersonWithConstraint1();

                //op.setToCorrectTimetableSlot();

                im.resetEveryTwoWeeksAndSetToCorrectTimeSlot(op);

                constraint.removePersonWithConstraint1();

                of.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are no information about `InputChange` and what is passed to `inputChange` here.

Comment: What is InputChange? Also when you initialize inputChange in constructor does it initialize wk1,wk2...wkn?

Comment: It is quite likely that you have not initialized `inputChange` or `inputChange.wk1`. Which is causing the NullPointerException when you try to check if it is selected. As mentioned previously though, we will need to see the `InputChange` class to be sure.

Comment: Below's my inputchange class

Comment: You don't show the code where your Constraint instance is created.

Comment: How do you construct the Constraint?

Comment: I constructed it within the DateRange class as provided

Comment: Arizzle is right!  After tons of debugging, this problem was SOLVED!  I created an instance of inputChange within the Constraint2 function, so that it wouldn't repeat the one that is created in DateRange().  The most possible reason was that inputChange wasn't created in the class Constraint while I *Thought* it was created as I made one in DateRange, which results in "inputChange = null", and therefore NullPointerException was thrown.